# MS SQL searching text field incorrectly

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I do this query:

```
select charindex('batteries',content) from searchpage_v5 
where content like '%batteries%' and tableid=29 and id=72
```

I'm using MS SQL 2008 SP3. The "content" column in the table is of type text.

I am getting the result "0" rather than no records. How is this possible. Surely if the column "content" had the text "batteries" in it, then charindex would return >0, but if it didn't have it, then the query would return no results?

Help!

Comment: I'm not familiar with mssql, but if you don't have good luck here you should try posting the question at dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? It should work

Comment: What happens when you `select *` instead of `select charindex...` ?

Comment: @user1717828's suggestion as to trying [dba.se] might be a good idea, but please **do not post a copy** of this question there. Rather, if you want to get help from that community, **request migration** of your question by flagging it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is not super clear on this but it says [`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) cannot be used on `text` columns. My guess is the parameter is truncated to `varchar(8000)` implicitly and that's why you get the strange result. If possible, you should change the datatype of the column to `varchar(max)` since [`text` is deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx).

Comment: Ah ha! I figured seeing as charindex returned 0 it wasn't in there but in future investigation it is in there, but just after the 8000th character! Thanks!